# How to find out which application uses speakers?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

Some application sending short beeps at random times after windows is returned from hibernate and sleep states. Is there any way to track down this program?

Update:

Problem solved by closing all programs. One of desktop widgets was responsible for the sound.
I think there is nicer solution for this problem...

Comment: If you click on the Speaker button on the bottom right, and click on Mixer, it will show all programs that can use the speaker. If you have browser opens (from experience), the usual suspect is Gmail chat, or Facebook Chat (or other web-based chat that you may have open).

Answer (score 1):

Enter `sndvol` into the start menu or right-click on the volume icon in the notification area of the taskbar and hit `Open Volume Mixer`. When an application makes a sound you should be able to see it visually here.

As for the cause, that would be application dependent.