# TeamViewer - local audio is disabled when connected to remote

Tags: audio, remote, teamviewer

I have the latest (free) version of TeamViewer running on my (Win 10) PC and I connect with it to a remote (Win 10) PC.
Lately (it wasn't like that until a few days ago!), I've noticed that as soon as I connect to the remote PC, the audio is totally disabled on the local PC.
By totally, I mean that everything that has to do with sound in the local PC is simply not working - no sound. Once I disconnect from the remote PC, the audio in the local PC is back on like nothing happened.
I went over all the settings in both the local PC and the remote PC and nothing that relates to audio/sound makes any difference for this situation.
Did someone encounter this situation? What do I need to do in order to fix that?

Comment: Did you just check the system settings or did you check the TeamViewer settings themselves? There is at least an option for remote audio transfer.

Comment: When I said I went over all the audio settings, I meant I did that on TV, not the OS itself, as there is nothing wrong with the OS itself. When I disconnect from the remote PC, everything is back to normal with the audio.

Answer (score 10):

I am one of several people who had the same issue. 
Here is a fix from the page [Bluetooth Sound lost
after connecting to a client](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-General/Bluetooth-Sound-lost-after-connecting-to-a-client/td-p/7629) (at TeamViewer.com).

Go to TeamViewer's Main screen and navigate to "Extras"
→ "Options" → "Audio Conferencing" → "Voice Playback". 
Change it to any device other than the one you are using for local audio.

Comment: Is that your complete answer?   It looks like you got interrupted in mid-word.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed that I cut it off. it is fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, I'd obviously be trying to ensure that that's the correct program that's causing the problem just to be certain that I'm not chasing my tail.

[How to determine which program is making a certain sound in windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/649729/how-to-determine-which-program-is-making-a-certain-sound-in-windows-7)

[What is using my sound card?](https://superuser.com/questions/784648/what-is-using-my-sound-card)

[How to find out which application uses speakers?](https://superuser.com/questions/684673/how-to-find-out-which-application-uses-speakers)

If that's true I'd be trying to re-check all settings (which you've done).

http://ccm.net/faq/30420-allow-sound-and-music-sharing-on-teamviewer

https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-12/Audio-Sound-problems-Please-help/td-p/1201

https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-12/There-is-no-sound-from-the-remote-computer/td-p/1300

If the settings don't display anything out of the ordinary I'd be trying to scrub all remnants of the program from the relevant systems so that I know it may not come down to a strange bug of some sort.

Then I'd probably try different versions of the program on both systems.

I'd also try TeamViewer support itself since they would know more about the inner workings of the program.

I'd also look at alternative sound drivers especially if your machine may double as a multimedia workstation. I've seen something similar to this before on a music workstation that had something to do with Asio4All drivers. Basically, the way the old driver worked and the new driver worked was very different which led to some odd sound blocking issues.

I'd also look to other programs that may be automatically started while TeamViewer is running. I've seen some really weird bugs with completely bizarre errors from time to time. This may be one of those circumstances.

As a last resort, programs to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It's happening with everyone who has updated to the latest version of TeamViewer and it's cannot be fixed until the next version, So just wait for the next update or use discord.

Answer (score -1):

Ever since I've posted this question, TV has gone through quite a few updates and changes, and the issue reported here has never occured again, so I find this not relevant any more, fortunately.

Comment: I had this issue just now. I may have enabled sound transfer at some earlier point in time, so it was still relevant to me.

Answer (score -1):

In your Windows Control Panel go to 'Sound'. Go to the tab 'Communications' and select 'do nothing'. Problem solved.